# What does it means Instance of Num [Int] required for definition of cuenta_signo?

Tags: haskell

```
cuenta_signo::[Int]->(Int,Int)
cuenta_signo l= ((length [a | a <- l, l < 0]), (length [b | b <- l, l > 0] ))
```

Why do I get the error "Instance of Num [Int] required for definition of cuenta_signo"?

Comment: Please post the **complete** error message. Are you using ghc or ghci?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`l` is of type `[Int]`. Unfortunately, the error message is confusing but it is because you are trying to use `<` and `>` to compare a list with a number (`l < 0`). You might have meant to compare with `a` and `b`.

Also, you should post the full error message as Code-Apprentice said, next time. That makes it easier to figure out what's going on and you'll probably get an answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

The less-than operator `(<)` can only be used to compare similar types. Since you have `l < 0` and `0` is a number (i.e. a `Num`), the compiler complains. You cannot compare a single number against a list of numbers with `(<)`.

Most likely you mean to compare the elements of the list, so `a < 0` and `b > 0` will likely get what you want. Note that `a` and `b` represents an individual element of the list `l` which are `Int`s, not `[Int]`.